# Creating Canvas GUI GameObjects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a terrible issue where if I create a new UI element on a canvas (such as a Button) drag it into the project files to create it as a prefab, delete it from the scene, and then Run my game, the prefab loses its Image and Button scripts. This is also happening to any image/text/UI element. Any time I make them prefabs, and then run the game, the lose their image/text/button/UI script.

Why is this?

Comment: I cant reproduce this scenario. please give me more information.

Comment: Have you checked [the Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html) to see what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @UriPopov Create a new project. Create a new scene. Create a canvas. Create any UI element. Drag the element to the project folder to create a prefab. Delete the UI element from the scene. Run the game. Check the prefab - The prefab is now missing its Image (or related) component.

Comment: @Varaquilex I did what the manual says, actually. But as soon as I remove the prefab from the Scene, it breaks the prefab when I run the game (even before instantiating it). It works if I keep it in the Scene (but that's not what I want)

Comment: Did exactly what you said. Still cant reproduce it. are using unity pro or the free version. i'm using unity pro.

Comment: @user3822370 did you try disabling the prefab in the scene rather than removing it? I believe Unity is bugged, UI bug happened to me on Unity 5. Can reproduce the bug on a fresh project?

Comment: I'm using the free unity. No, I don't seem to be able to do this on a fresh project, but if I create a clean scene in my project with no game objects (so no scripts running), it occurs.

Comment: I maybe just found my issue http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/suddenly-all-ui-scripts-missing.322760/

Comment: Finally, the top comment in that thread fixed my issue. My UI was just totally broken